# Rep wiki does not tally with review queue

Tags: bug, review, user-interface, tag-wiki, privileges

**Consider exhibit A:**

[image]

I have recently been granted privilege "Access Review Queues". However, I am unable to "find" the review link on the top navigation bar, as stated clearly in the wiki.

---

**Exhibit B:**

[image]

Although I know the link to the review queue (`/review`), there is a link in the wiki as well. Following it to the review queue page, I found that this page is useless to me even though I can access this page.

---

**Questions:**

1. Review link at the top of the page - is it intentionally hidden because I cannot access any of the review queues? If yes, wiki page needs to reflect this clearly.
2. Why the privilege is awarded to access the review page, even though the review queues are not accessible?